# How to prevent a Qt/GTK app (Calibre) from using colors defined in .Xresources?

Tags: x11, colors, gtk, x-resources, calibre

I have colors defined in .Xresources. They look lovely on urxvt, and utterly ghastly on Calibre.

Calibre does not appear to have any way to disable or override those colors, so is there any way I can invoke Calibre that would ignore my color scheme?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The string in Xresources usually looks like this:

```
 name.Class.resource: value
```

Looks like you use * in place of name and class:

```
*color0: black
```

Which means you apply color to everything.

If you want apply colors to urxvt only:

```
URxvt*color0: black
```

Answer (score 1):

Although being more specific in your .Xresources file can solve the problem, it's not the perfect workaround if you really do intend to use wildcard selectors.

Another workaround is to unload your .Xresources file before launching calibre, and reload it afterwards:

```
xrdb -remove ~/.Xresources && calibre & sleep 5; xrdb -load ~/.Xresources
```